# Finding the lowest Time value in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, time, max, min

I'm trying to find the lowest time value, that would equate to the starting point of trip, in a data frame for a `DeviceID`. This value should be the lowest value from a time range e.g. 11:00:00 - 13:00:00 (Lunch time peak hour - LT_Peak).

Similarly I also have to run a command to find the maximum time value, which would equate to the ending point of a trip.

I will need to apply this command throughout the whole data frame for all the `DeviceID` and find the starting and ending point for each one.

I've tried using this function: 
`Start = df4.loc[df.Time>0, 'Time'].idxmin()
 End = df4.loc[df.Time>0, 'Time'].idxmax()`

But I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'`

My dataframe looks like this:

```
DeviceID    Long        Lat         Date        Time        Peak_Hour   
50047047    55.24465    23.98627    2018-05-03  12:33:12    LT Peak
50047047    55.25749    23.98707    2018-05-03  12:34:13    LT Peak
50047047    55.27011    23.98787    2018-05-03  12:35:13    LT Peak 
50047047    55.23195    23.98817    2018-05-03  12:32:11    LT Peak 
50047047    55.28297    23.98868    2018-05-03  12:36:14    LT Peak
```

The result after running the command would look like this:

StartDf =

```
DeviceID    Long        Lat         Date        Time        Peak_Hour   
50047047    55.24465    23.98627    2018-05-03  12:32:11    LT Peak
```

EndDf =

```
DeviceID    Long        Lat         Date        Time        Peak_Hour   
50047047    55.24465    23.98627    2018-05-03  12:36:14    LT Peak
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your dictionary by the time row and than take the last and first element.

Answer (score 0):

is your time column in 24 hour format? if it is, create a new column that combines date & time column.

Set your datetime column as index and then sort the index ascending.

Use df.head(1) and df. tail(1) to get the minimum and maximum.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: One thing though, the complete dataframe has time values for the entire day. I am looking for the head and tail for a specific time period/range. So I would want the head and tail for: AM Peak, LT Peak and PM Peak. And just sorting the column in ascending form would just give me the AM and PM values.